# Show time durations on a d3 axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, timespan

I am currently creating a d3 axis using `d3.time.scale.utc()`. My input for the axis is a series of time offsets in minutes (with decimal values). For example:

```
var minuteOffsets = [0.03, 1.65, 3.22, ..., 89.91, 90.01];
```

I want to display these time offsets in `mm:ss` format on the axis. The axis labels can be at standard intervals, like so:

```
  +------+------+-- ... --+------+------+-- ... --+------+
00:00  00:30  01:00     59:30  60:00  60:30     90:00  90:30
```

Note specifically that the minute value should show values >60. The seconds value has the normal range 0-59.

When I tried using `.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%M:%S'))`, it wraps the minute value back to `00:00` after the `45:00` label. I also had a look at `duration` from moment.js, but I can't figure out how exactly to incorporate that into my code.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use a time scale, but a linear scale. You can pass the values as they are to the scale and in the formatting function convert them to the `mm:ss` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comment by Lars Kotthoff, I changed my scale to be a linear scale, instead of a time scale. Then I added a custom `tickFormat` function to do the necessary formatting.

I used MomentJS to first create a `duration` from the minute values, and then used the library [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to produce the tick label in `mm:ss` format.

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(function (d) {
    return moment.duration(d, 'minutes')
                 .format('mm:ss', { trim: false });
});
```

This helps to avoid explicitly writing code for extracting the minute and second components, and then formatting them into a string.